# How do you copy from tmux (copy mode) running on a remote ssh connection to your local clipboard

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, tmux

I run linux via VirtualBox on OS X. I do this by running my VM in a headless state and then sshing to the linux machine using port forwarding. Right now whatever is copied to my clipboard on my virtual machine I am able to paste on my remote ssh session, but not vice versa (copying from tmux copy mode). I have tried using the following tmux configurations:

```
setw -g mode-keys vi
bind-key -t vi-copy v begin-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy y copy-pipe "tmux save-buffer - | ssh host pbcopy"
```

Unfortunately this is not working... Manually copying using my mouse works but tmux copy mode is more convenient. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the version of tmux on your OSX?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yeah, Ram's answer did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This needs integrating tmux buffers with OSX clipboard. What you are trying to do with `ssh host pbcopy` is just that but I don't think your setup is correct.

`host` here should be your local OSX machine. And you should have password less key-based trust established between your OSX username and remote user where you are running tmux.

**Step 1.** Enable SSH on your OSX
 Goto `System preferences -> Sharing` and enable `Remote Login`. Also remove administrators from the list and add your username.

**Step 2.** Setup password less login.
These are the [steps](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)

**Step 3.** Replace your `host` with `192.x.x.x` or whatever your OSX's ipaddress is which is reachable from your Virtualbox

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work... To clarify, I'm running tmux on Linux via ssh and want to be able to put whatever is yanked on tmux onto my local OS X clipboard.

Comment: yes you are right... I will have the answer corrected.

Comment: It was the passwordless login that I forgot to configure. It works perfectly now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is answered, but just want to provide an alternative solution;

copy text in tmux copy mode from remote host to local system was always a pain for me, I use a windows laptop to SSH into remote system a lot, but apparently there was no good way to do the remote copy, specially when you have more than one screen of text to copy...

so I wrote a tool: [rclip](https://github.com/hujun-open/rclip), which uses tmux's copy-pipe command to pipe copied text to rclip, and rclip will forward text over network to a rclip process running on local system, which will copy the received text to system clipboard; all communication is authenticated and encrypted via TLS; give it a try, I am quite happy with it