# tmux 2.1 in ssh session: mouse events & making copy-paste local (ubuntu --> ubuntu)

Tags: select, ssh, mouse, clipboard, tmux

I ssh from my ubuntu machine to a remote (also ubuntu) machine and run tmux 2.1 there.  I would like to use mouse events to change/resize panes while still being able to select/copy/paste from the remote to the local machine.  If I `set -g mouse off`, my local select/copy/paste works, with the caveat that it does not recognize pane boundaries.  I tried:

`set -g mouse on
unbind MouseDrag1Pane`

This allows for the pane selection/resize, but the mouse drag still triggers tmux's copy mode. (Why?)  So:

**(1)** is there some way to have mouse selection/resize of pane on, without interfering with local selection & copy?

**(2)** Even better, is there some way to select/copy on the remote machine and have that passed through to the local machine so that pane boundaries will be recognized?  Note that I can not ssh from remote to local, as with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062030/how-do-you-copy-from-tmux-copy-mode-running-on-a-remote-ssh-connection-to-your), which might otherwise work using [linux's equivalents to pbcopy](https://superuser.com/questions/288320/whats-like-osxs-pbcopy-for-linux).

**Possible Approaches to (2)?** Not an expert at this, but a couple of thoughts:

- Perhaps I could output the remote clipboard into a remote file, which I could pole from the local end and, when it changes, copy it to the local clipboard?
- Or, perhaps when I ssh to the remote, I might also set up a reverse tunnel which could be used to shuttle something back to the local machine?

---

Also note that when experimenting I found that changing mouse options in my `.tmux.conf` and running: `source-file ~/.tmux.conf` does not change the `mouse on/off` option.  I have to terminate and restart tmux to see what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two easy things to try:

1. As of tmux 1.8, pane zoom works out of the box: [leader]z.  This lets you zoom a pane to full screen. This makes copies possible even when you have vertically split panes because the others are temporarily hidden.  If you are stuck with an older tmux, there are ways to simulate this zoom with key bindings.
2. Try holding down the shift key, then click and drag to select text.  Right click selection and copy. This will copy to your local clipboard.

Comment: By "pane zoom" I think you mean the `break-pane` command, right?  Then I'd use `join-pane` to return the pane from where it came.  (While `break-pane` works, `join-pane` doesn't seem to work out of the box, at least not the way I'm trying to use it.)  Since `unbind MouseDrag1Pane` is not working to allow me to select text without triggering tmux's copy mode, I would have to combine the three to get something that kind of works (though is a bit round about: break, shift-select, join, assuming there is a way to get the latter to work).

Comment: Nope.  This is what I meant: ```bind-key  z resize-pane -Z```.  See [zooming-tmux-panes](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/zooming-tmux-panes/).

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying.  Apparently z is already bound to that command.